# Variable values changes from test method to tearDownClass python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nose, python-unittest

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.test_passes = 'error'
    <some code here...>

def test_validate(self):
    try:
        self.test_passes = 'ok'
        sys.stderr.write(str(cls.test_passes)) #The value of test_passes is `ok`
    except AssertionError:
        self.github_pr_list()

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.repo.push()
    sys.stderr.write(str(cls.test_passes)) #But here the value of error changes
```

So I am trying to instantiate a variable in `setUpClass` by the value of `error` and then in test method the value successfully changes to `ok` but then in `tearDownClass` again the value is reverted to `error`, even though it should be `ok`? Why is the value getting changed, and what do I need to do to resolve it?

Comment: You've left out some pretty critical code; are you actually calling these methods sequentially on the same object instantiated from that class?  You don't show that code.

Comment: Why are you tagging this with `python-2.7` AND `python-3.x`? Which is it?

Comment: No they are not called sequentially, `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` are generic for test methods (Class TestTemplate), so they inherit `unittest.TestCase`, and then `test_validate` inherits `TestTemplate`, so its basically inheritance. @DavidHoelzer